# Approximating evalutation maps at open sets over invariant measures

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, descriptive-set-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting by homeomorphisms on a compact metrizable space, say $X$; let's denote by $\alpha:G\to\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ the action, $g\mapsto\alpha_g$, and consider the weak-$^*$ compact simplex of Borel probability measures on $X$ that are invariant under the action, let's call this $\mathcal{M}_\alpha(X)$. I am wondering about the following property:

For any open set $U\subset X$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a compact subset $K\subset U$ so that $\mu(U)\ge\mu(K)\ge\mu(U)-\varepsilon$ for all $\mu\in\mathcal{M}_\alpha(X)$.

Clearly, if $\mathcal{M}_\alpha(X)$ has finite extreme points (i.e. the *ergodic* invariant measures are finite), this is immediately satisfied, simply by regularity of each of the extreme points. But under what more general assumptions does this appear, or what kind of obstructions does this property have? Not sure if this is relevant, but note that the map $\mu\mapsto\mu(U)$ is lower semicontinuous while $\mu\mapsto\mu(K)$ would be upper semicontinuous.

I'd appreciate any references about this.